# it is possible to catch a standard related object edit change, from a lightning WEB component that is placed into a record page?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I need to refresh a custom table, when a related object is updated from the standard edit UI.

This is the Javascript File.

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import getEconomicPlan from '@salesforce/apex/EconomicPlanController.getEconomicPlan';
import getTotalEconomicPlan from '@salesforce/apex/EconomicPlanController.getTotalEconomicPlan'
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';


export default class BasicDatatable extends LightningElement {

recordsBuffer;
recordsBuffer2;

@track quote;
@track data = [];
@track data2 = [];
@track error = [];
@track error2 = [];

@api recordId;



@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: ['Quote.TotalHRCost__c', 'Quote.TotalQuotaATI__c', ' Quote.Total_Revenue__c', 'Quote.Total_Cost__c'] })
getQuoteRecord({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
        this.quote = data;
        console.log('DATA => ', JSON.stringify(data))
        this.refresh();
    } else if (error) {
        console.error('ERROR => ', JSON.stringify(error));
    }
}

@wire
    (getEconomicPlan, { quoteID: '$recordId' })
economicPlan(recordsBuffer) {
    this.recordsBuffer = recordsBuffer;
    const { data, error } = recordsBuffer;
    if (data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.error = undefined;

    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
        this.data = undefined;
        console.error('ERROR => ', JSON.stringify(error));
    }
};

@wire
    (getTotalEconomicPlan, { totalQuoteID: '$recordId' })
totaleconomicPlan(recordsBuffer2) {
    this.recordsBuffer2 = recordsBuffer2;
    const { data, error } = recordsBuffer2;
    if (data) {
        this.data2 = data;
        this.error2 = undefined;

    } else if (error) {
        this.error2 = error;
        this.data2 = undefined;
        console.error('ERROR => ', JSON.stringify(error));
    }
};

@api
refresh() {
    console.log('refresh ');
    refreshApex(this.recordsBuffer)
    return refreshApex(this.recordsBuffer2);
};

}
```

This the HTML file.

```
 <template>
  <lightning-button-icon class="slds-float_right" icon-name="utility:refresh" onfocus={refresh} tabindex="0"  alternative-text="Refresh" onclick={refresh}></lightning-button-icon>
  <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-no-row-hover slds-table_bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
        <th class="" scope="col">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Revenue Type">Revenue Type</div>
        </th>
        <th class="" scope="col">
          <div class="slds-truncate right" title="HR Cost">HR Cost</div>
        </th>
        <th class="" scope="col">
          <div class="slds-truncate right" title="Cost">Cost</div>
        </th>
        <th class="" scope="col">
          <div class="slds-truncate right" title="Revenue">Revenue</div>
        </th>
        <th class="" scope="col">
          <div class="slds-truncate right" title="ATI">ATI</div>
        </th>
        <th class="" scope="col">
          <div class="slds-truncate right" title="Profit">Profit</div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <template for:each={data} for:item="datas">
        <tr key={datas.revenueType} class="slds-hint-parent ">
          <th data-label="Revenue Type" scope="row">
            <div class="slds-truncate " title={datas.revenueType}>{datas.revenueType}</div>
          </th>
          <td data-label="HR Cost">
            <p class="slds-truncate right">
              <lightning-formatted-number value={datas.costHR} format-style="currency" currency-code="EUR"
                currency-display-as="symbol"></lightning-formatted-number>
            </p>
          </td>
          <td data-label="Cost">
            <p class="slds-truncate right">
              <lightning-formatted-number value={datas.cost} format-style="currency" currency-code="EUR"
                currency-display-as="symbol"></lightning-formatted-number>
            </p>
          </td>
          <td data-label="Revenue">
            <p class="slds-truncate right">
              <lightning-formatted-number value={datas.revenue} format-style="currency" currency-code="EUR"
                currency-display-as="symbol"></lightning-formatted-number>
            </p>
          </td>
          <td data-label="ATI">
            <p class="slds-truncate right">
              <lightning-formatted-number value={datas.ATI} format-style="currency" currency-code="EUR"
                currency-display-as="symbol"></lightning-formatted-number>
            </p>
          </td>
          <td data-label="Profit">
            <p class="slds-truncate right">
              <lightning-formatted-number value={datas.profit} format-style="percent"></lightning-formatted-number>
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </template>

<tr class=" slds-box slds-theme_shade slds-theme_alert-texture ">
    <th data-label="Revenue Type" class="  slds-theme_shade slds-theme_alert-texture " scope="row">
        <div class="slds-truncate slds-theme_shade slds-theme_alert-texture last-row-bold" title={data2.revenueType}>
            {data2.revenueType}</div>
    </th>
    <td data-label="HR Cost">
        <p class="slds-truncate  slds-theme_shade slds-theme_alert-texture last-row-bold right">
            <lightning-formatted-number value={data2.costHR} format-style="currency" currency-code="EUR" currency-display-as="symbol"></lightning-formatted-number>
        </p>
    </td>
    <td data-label="Cost">
        <p class="slds-truncate  slds-theme_shade slds-theme_alert-texture last-row-bold right">
            <lightning-formatted-number value={data2.cost} format-style="currency" currency-code="EUR" currency-display-as="symbol"></lightning-formatted-number>
        </p>
    </td>
    <td data-label="Revenue">
        <p class="slds-truncate  slds-theme_shade slds-theme_alert-texture last-row-bold right">
            <lightning-formatted-number value={data2.revenue} format-style="currency" currency-code="EUR" currency-display-as="symbol"></lightning-formatted-number>
        </p>
    </td>
    <td data-label="ATI">
        <p class="slds-truncate  slds-theme_shade slds-theme_alert-texture last-row-bold right">
            <lightning-formatted-number value={data2.ATI} format-style="currency" currency-code="EUR" currency-display-as="symbol"></lightning-formatted-number>
        </p>
    </td>
    <td data-label="Profit">
        <p class="slds-truncate slds-theme_shade slds-theme_alert-texture last-row-bold right">
            <lightning-formatted-number value={data2.profit} format-style="percent"></lightning-formatted-number>
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

For all my use cases, I personally have been able to get away with the quick and dirty solution of polling the server from the client. But in looking at solutions, the hypothetical "right" way of doing it would be to create a change handler for your standard object that you're tracking, then subscribe to that handler via push notifications to your lightning component.

Change Events:
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/08/what-is-change-data-capture.html

Subscribing to Platform Events:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/workshop-platform-events/platform-event-subscribe

As a word of warning, our org found out the hard way that the Unlimited edition has a hard limit of 5 objects that can track changes through change events, without additional licensing. A workaround would be to create a normal platform event, and publish to it every time that a relevant change happens to the object you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Nathanael Schmolze. This Works.
Just needed to set the events channels into the "Change Data Capture" Setup setting.

```
@api
refresh() {
    console.log('refresh');
    refreshApex(this.recordsBuffer);
    refreshApex(this.recordsBuffer2);
    return;
};

async connectedCallback() {
    const messageCallback = response => {
        console.log('New message received: ', JSON.stringify(response));
        this.refresh();
    };

    subscribe("/data/ChangeEvents", -1, messageCallback).then(response => {
        console.log('Subscription request sent to: ', JSON.stringify(response.channel));
        this.subscription = response;
    });


}
```